# ASP.NET MVC Remote attribute method parameter always passing null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this `AdvertiserNameAvailable` method that is being used by Remote validation attribute.
The problem is that the `AdvertiserNameAvailable` is being called without passing the input value to the method `Name` parameter. When I enter in debug into the method, I see that the `Name` parameter is always `null`.

```
  public JsonResult AdvertiserNameAvailable(string Name)
  {
      return Json("Some custom error message", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }

  public class AdvertiserAccount
  {
      [Required]
      [Remote("AdvertiserNameAvailable", "Accounts")]
      public string Name
      {
          get;
          set;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 15):

Had to add `[Bind(Prefix = "account.Name")]`

```
public ActionResult AdvertiserNameAvailable([Bind(Prefix = "account.Name")] String name)
{
    if(name == "Q")
    {
        return  Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return  Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

To find out your prefix, right click and do inspect element on the input that you are trying to validate. Look for the `name` attribute:

```
<input ... id="account_Name" name="account.Name" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult AdvertiserNameAvailable(string Name)
  {
    bool isNameAvailable = CheckName(Name);  //validate Name and return true of false
    return Json(isNameAvailable );     
  }

  public class AdvertiserAccount
  {
      [Required]
      [Remote("AdvertiserNameAvailable", "Accounts", HttpMethod="Post", ErrorMessage = "Some custom error message.")]     
      public string Name
      {
          get;
          set;
      }
  }
```

Also to note:

> The OutputCacheAttribute attribute is required in order to prevent
>   ASP.NET MVC from caching the results of the validation methods.

So use `[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]` on your controller action.