# issues in MVC remote validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

My code is like this

```
   public class Payer
{
    public int PayerId { get; set; }
    [Remote("PayerNameExists", "Payer", "Payer name  already exists.", AdditionalFields = "PayerID"), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double PatientContribution { get; set; }
}
```

Inside controller

```
 public JsonResult PayerNameExists(string Name,int PayerID=0)
{

    var user = db.Payer.Where(x => x.Name == Name.Trim()&&x.PayerId!=PayerID);
    return !user.Any() ?
        Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) :
        Json(string.Format("{0} is already exists.", Name),
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and in view (`Edit`)

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```

My problem is that inside the function `PayerNameExists`  `PayerID` always comes as `zero` I expect to get my model ID out there. Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Note: Data send from client side is liek this

> /Payer/PayerNameExists?area=Payer%20name%20%20already%20exists.&Name=ICICIx&PayerID=undefined

Comment: why have you assigned player Id as 0 in `public JsonResult PayerNameExists(string Name,int PayerID=0)`... Remove this and retest

Comment: Are you rendering a control in the view for `PayerID`? - e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PayerID)`?

Comment: Maybe is a missing Bind attribute? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330783/asp-net-mvc-remote-attribute-method-parameter-always-passing-null

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes. I am rendering it

Comment: @Juan tried. not working

Comment: @TusharGupta tried not working. I have updated my question. check it too

Comment: @Athul Ur player id will always come as 0 because u r assigning it as 0 on  the param.. Also the url hit says `PayerID=undefined` which is not a number

Comment: @TusharGupta That is the actual issue here. Why PayerID is undefined??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a miss-match in `PayerID` and `PayerId` this:

```
AdditionalFields = "PayerID"
```

It needs to be this:

```
AdditionalFields = "PayerId"
```

And you method needs to be this:

```
public JsonResult PayerNameExists(string Name,int PayerId=0)
```

Or change you model to:

```
public int PayerID { get; set; }
```

**Update**

I needed to change the model to `PayerID` as mentioned above to get this working, not all agree as it was downvoted.

However I also needed to do the following:

Supply an `Html.Helper` to post the `PayerID` back i.e. `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PayerID)`, otherwise it was going to the default.

If you are having an un-specified error you may want to check the rendered html, it will need to have something like the following:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-remote="'Name' is invalid." data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Name,*.PayerID" data-val-remote-url="/Home/PayerNameExists" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="Name" class="input-validation-error">
```

Note `data-val-remote-additionalfields` as this is what jquery needs to render to find the additional properties, if it is different or missing the setting up has failed so check you have references for `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"` also jquery.

The attribute would not work for me, I had to remove the error message. This comes back from the server anyway.

```
    [Remote("PayerNameExists", "Home", AdditionalFields = "PayerID"), Required]
```

Also from you rendered link in the update i.e.

```
/Payer/PayerNameExists?area=Payer%20name%20%20already%20exists.&Name=ICICIx&PayerID=undefined
```

It is picking up your intended error message as an area route value, so remove it as I mentioned above.

**Screen shots**

[image: debug]

[image: output]

Comment: Tried , Still same error. from cliend side it's send like PayerID=undefined

Comment: @Athul Just change the model instead then to match `PayerID` instead and it should pick it up.

Comment: @Athul, The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive so the parameter name could be `pAyERiD` and it would bind, but javascript is, so it needs to be `AdditionalFields = "PayerId"` if the property name is `PayerId`. If that  does not fix it, use you browser tools to put a breakpoint on the `remote` function in jquery.validate.js and check the values.